# Ubuntu 20.04 connection times out

Tags: command-line, apt, server, 20.04, connection

I was trying to apply "sudo apt-get update" command. However when I run the command, I get output like this;

```
berke@berke-ABRA-A5-V15-8:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable InRelease                                                                 
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                           
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                              
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tsbarnes/indicator-keylock/ubuntu focal InRelease                                            
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/earth/deb stable Release                                                                   
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                      
Hit:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                                                              
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                              
Hit:11 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                          
Err:12 http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease            
Could not connect to tr.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (193.140.98.183), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                            
W: Failed to fetch http://tr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Could not connect to tr.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (193.140.98.183), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

After this step I also tried to change the server as "Main Server". Yet, that didn't solve the time out error. What is the solution for this time out error in Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa?

Answer (score 0):

That server seems to be down for me as well, so changing your settings to use a different one (as I think you have done) would probably fix the issue.

If you haven't already done so, try entering `sudo apt-get update` after changing the server to "Main server". Does it still try to connect to the same unresponsive server?

Comment: After a while from changing server to "Main Server" and rebooting, problem solved by itself. It works fine now.